# Custom Label translations in Lightning Component input attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, translation, lightning-builder

We are currently busy setting up a multi language Lightning community. My question is if we can use `{!$Label.c.MY_TRANSLATED_LABEL}` as an input attribute in out-of-the-box Lightning Components? This doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried some custom Lightning Components with the same result.

I'm testing this with the ootb 'User Profile Menu' component to translate the options:
 - My Profile
 - Logout
 - ...

Comment: How exactly do you try to show the label? please share your code. I am using in my community custom labels with translations, so it is possible

Comment: Did you figure this out ? Even I am finding ways to support translation for OOB components like LoginForm etc